# Spring Boot and Logging with External Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, logging, log4j2

I am deploying my Spring Boot Application on an external Tomcat Server. I can't seem to make my eclipse console display the log messages that I write in my code:

```
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonServiceImpl.class);
...
log.info("Running...");
```

I managed to log all hibernate trace but still can't show the log messages I am adding to my code:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
logging.level.root=INFO
logging.level.org.springframework.web=INFO
```

And the catalina log folder doesn't contain the logged infos I am needing.

What should I do?

Comment: Does this `log.info("Running...");` is printing or not after adding `logging` config

Comment: Hi Chayma, could you please provide more info, actually the log you have on your console like starting server, in the other hand, you can search on the log folder of your external tomcat to check if your custom logs are there ?

Comment: @Hatim thank you for your answer but no they aren't there.

Comment: @AjitSoman no it is still not printing

Answer (score 0):

Please configure your application.properties or application.yml
file


application.properties

```
#Logging pattern for file.
logging.pattern.file= "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"

#output to a file 
logging.file=/path_to_file/file_name.log

#Logging pattern for console and output.
logging.pattern.console= "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but can you please explain what each line is doing

Comment: Doing this only changed my log file location but the logging instruction I added in code is still not showing

Comment: Hi @ChaymaAtallah, i have made code description on top of each line.
you set your logging ROOT to info, so you will not be able to see TRACE and DEBUG.

Comment: If still not working , you can share your code via email also.